# Como Pegar os dados especificos de um JSON com Angular 2x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-6

Tenho um resposta que transformo em JSON desta forma:

```
const resposta = JSON.stringify(response);

              console.log(resposta);
```

Me dá o retorno no console.log desta forma:

```
[{"nome":"Ramos Janones","email":"ramos@ramosdainformatica.com.br","cpf":"03472925698","celular":"34996320391","telefone":"","cep":"38300070","endereco":"DEZESSEIS","cidade":"Ituiutaba","estado":"Minas Gerais","bairro":"","complemento":"","usuario":"ramos","senha":"teste123","idppoker":"","nickppocker":"ramosinfo","numero":"","_id":"5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7","createdAt":"2018-11-18T15:59:13.735Z","updatedAt":"2018-11-26T15:41:00.806Z","__v":0,"id":"5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7","foto":{"_id":"5bfc140dbe257a17900442a1","name":"8.jpg","sha256":"Mt3053NTSRC81wiHOEMubEUagRAPlHOR-MtPvf2yKgQ","hash":"36cdc8491d7b4fa1817bed8126b3143e","ext":".jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","size":"58.46","url":"/uploads/36cdc8491d7b4fa1817bed8126b3143e.jpg","provider":"local","related":["5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7"],"createdAt":"2018-11-26T15:41:01.003Z","updatedAt":"2018-11-26T15:41:04.113Z","__v":0,"id":"5bfc140dbe257a17900442a1"},"contasJogadors":[]}]
```

Como posso pegar os valores que quiser para colocar em um localStorage?

Pesquisei antes de postar esta dúvida, tentei as várias formas e não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> O método map() invoca a função callback passada por argumento para
>   cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.

Você poderia utilizar o array map, ele faz um loop e retorna um novo array com as modificações que quiser, inclusive removendo ou adicionando campos conforme precisar:

```js
var data = [{"nome":"Ramos Janones","email":"ramos@ramosdainformatica.com.br","cpf":"03472925698","celular":"34996320391","telefone":"","cep":"38300070","endereco":"DEZESSEIS","cidade":"Ituiutaba","estado":"Minas Gerais","bairro":"","complemento":"","usuario":"ramos","senha":"teste123","idppoker":"","nickppocker":"ramosinfo","numero":"","_id":"5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7","createdAt":"2018-11-18T15:59:13.735Z","updatedAt":"2018-11-26T15:41:00.806Z","__v":0,"id":"5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7","foto":{"_id":"5bfc140dbe257a17900442a1","name":"8.jpg","sha256":"Mt3053NTSRC81wiHOEMubEUagRAPlHOR-MtPvf2yKgQ","hash":"36cdc8491d7b4fa1817bed8126b3143e","ext":".jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","size":"58.46","url":"/uploads/36cdc8491d7b4fa1817bed8126b3143e.jpg","provider":"local","related":["5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7"],"createdAt":"2018-11-26T15:41:01.003Z","updatedAt":"2018-11-26T15:41:04.113Z","__v":0,"id":"5bfc140dbe257a17900442a1"},"contasJogadors":[]}]

var maped = data.map(function(item){
  
  return {nome: item.nome, email: item.email}
})
console.log(maped)
```

Utilizando o código basta retornar os campos que deseja e depois salvar o novo array como desejar

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Obrigado @edson alves. Perfeito.